# Plotting a 43x3 shaped numpy array in 3D

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a 43x3 shaped numpy array. Every row has x, y and z coordinates of a 3D point cloud point. In total there are 43 of them. When I try to plot them with:

```
plt.plot(arr)
plt.show()
```

the figure comes out like this:

[image]

I wish to plot the "arr" in 3D with each row corresponding to each point. What do you guys think? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
arr = [[0,0,0]] # your array
axes = plt.axes(projection="3d")
 
x = arr[:,0]
y = arr[:, 1]
z = arr[:, 2]

ax.plot3D(x, y, z, 'red')
```

Answer (score 0):

To draw in 3D you need [axes](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.html) that support it:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(sublot_kw={'projection': '3d'})
```

You can either plot the data:

```
ax.plot(*arr.T, ls='none')
```

Or you can [scatter plot](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/scatter3d.html) it:

```
ax.scatter(*arr.T)
```